# Using content management system with iOS or Android

Tags: android, ios, html, user-interface, content-management-system

I want to develop a application where part of the data is dynamic like picture , show timing etc.Their are many content management system that use HTML5 and CSS but i want to also use the native iOS or Android Ui like the UISplitView for iPad.How is this possible ? whats the best way to manage and use dynamic data ?

Comment: Does ContentProvider pattern lack any required feature ?

Answer (score 0):

I have been digging into this very exact answer. The best answer I can come up with is called parse.com. Which may not be 100% of what you are looking for. However. What it does is serve as a central database that talks to multiple platforms(windows 8, iOS, Android) and offers up an api for use with every platform with lots of documentation to make programming super easy. http://deployd.com/ also This site is something Ill be looking into which uses a simplified node.js desktop for programming easy objective based functions with a database. Definitely am still looking. Either way the bast thing is to call your view...bring in a few objects...and have these databases feed your objects to specifically answer your question.

As a developer Im used to Joomla and magento. These arent necessarily ios friendly. Anyway, best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest taking a look at Cloud CMS (http://www.cloudcms.com).

Cloud CMS is a cloud content management system that is built around JSON schema.  Unlike traditional web content systems, Cloud CMS works with JSON and binary files (either through MongoDB GridFS or Amazon S3).  It provides full-text search, structured query and an entire suite of enterprise features for things like workflow, analytics, users and groups and more.

From an iOS or Android viewpoint, you really only need to interact with the REST API.  You can do that directly or use one of the client libraries.

Disclaimer: I'm one of the founders of the company.  Would love to find out what you think and learn what we can do to improve things.  We're having a great time reinventing CMS for mobile.